# Using Angular ng-class for three possible options

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

With **angular.js** how can I use **ng-class** with three possible options?

If `status == 'active'` I want to add class `progress-bar-success`. If `status == 'terminated'` I want to add class `progress-bar-danger` else add class `progress-bar-info`.

Answer (score 3):

3 conditions:

```
ng-class="{'progress-bar-success':status == 'active', 'progress-bar-danger':status == 'terminated', 'progress-bar-info' : status != 'terminated' || status != 'active'}"
```

Comment: `status = active` is using `progress-bar-info` instead of `progress-bar-success`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a lot of stuff when your variable changes, and want to keep your html simple, you could do store the "status" variable in a service and all do the logic in a controller.

In your controller :

```
$scope.$watch(yourService.status, function(newVal) {
        switch(newval){
            case "active":
                $scope.progressbar_class = "progress-bar-success"
                [.. a lot of other stuff...]
                break
            case "terminated":
                $scope.progressbar_class = "progress-bar-danger"
                [.. a lot of other stuff...]
                break
            default:
                $scope.progressbar_class = "progress-bar-info"
                [.. a lot of other stuff...]
                break
        }

    }, true);
```

Your HTML would then simply be

```
<div class="progressbar {{progressbar_class}}"></div>
```

If you need something really simple, the other answer from tymeJV is much shorter.